# subinterfaces redeclaring abstract methods

Tags: java, interfaces, java8

Why is it that some abstract methods in interface hierarchies are redeclared as abstract further down?

`iterator()` for example, abstract in `Collection` is redeclared in `Set` and `List`, and again further down the Set hierarchy in `NavigableSet`.

I'd like to understand why this is done from a design point of view, or if there's some historical reason, etc. (I haven't seen anything about it in texts I've read sofar, and could not find anything in the JLS).

It is similar with other methods in `Collection`: add, size, remove, removeAll, clear, contains, containsAll, equals, isEmpty

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/564041)

Comment: @Filip Thanks for the link though the answer there isn't really clear to me. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/564165/724099) is clearer - that if a super interface is added later, it's accepted practice to not delete the methods. The examples I mentioned though - `Collection`, `List`, `Set` - are from the same version, 1.2. `NavigableSet` is from 1.6.